# MAUI CollectionView Header not showing

Tags: header, maui, collectionview

Learning MAUI, coming from a limited experience with WPF.

I have a CollectionView with 2 columns of data. I want to put a header on each column of data. The following code does not show any headers

````
            
            <CollectionView EmptyView="No data available" HorizontalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="150" ItemsSource="{Binding PropertyDetails}"  >
                
                <CollectionView.Header>
                        <Grid >
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Label Text="Address" Grid.Column="0"/>
                            <Label Text="Cost" Grid.Column="1"/>
                        </Grid>
                </CollectionView.Header>
                
               

The following code snips do show a header

            <CollectionView EmptyView="No data available" HorizontalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="150" ItemsSource="{Binding PropertyDetails}"  Header="My header">```


OR

                <CollectionView.Header>
                    My Header                 
                </CollectionView.Header>

but this only gives me a simple unformattable header for the whole collectionview and not for each column of data.


I have read a couple of posts on SO and google put they don't quite fit my issue.

I have also tried with a CollectionView.HeaderTemplate but that failed as well

Ideally I want to get better formatting for the headers but for now I will be glad to get them visible.

What, if anything have I missed?

Many thanks

Kevin
````

Comment: try assigning a height to the grid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On **Android** and **iOS**, the `HeaderTemplate` property can be set to `DataTemplate` objects that are used to format the header. In this scenario, the `Header` property must bind to the current source for the templates to be applied, as shown in the following example:

```
<CollectionView     Header="{Binding .}"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Monkeys}"
                    ItemsLayout="VerticalGrid, 2">
            <CollectionView.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid >
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Label  Grid.Column="0" Margin="10,0,0,0" 
                                Text="Address"  BackgroundColor="LightGray"  
                                FontSize="12" FontAttributes="Bold"/>

                        <Label Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,0,0,0"  
                                Text="Cost" BackgroundColor="LightGray"   
                                FontSize="12" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.HeaderTemplate>
              
             //Omitted for brevity
```

On **Winodws**, there's a known issue:[CollectionView Header & Footer not showing #14557](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/14557) on displaying the **header**, you can follow up there:https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/14557.

**Output:**

[image]

**UPDATE:**

The issue has been fixed, see:https://github.com/dotnet/maui/pull/16870

Comment: Hi Alexander. Thanks for the reply. I have marked it as the answer. Really need this to work on Windows so I guess I will have to wait for the known issue to be resolved. Thanks again